# Joomla Get ordered foreach from database

Tags: database, foreach, joomla

I have this code where I am geting data from database. All is ok.

```
<?php 
// Get DB;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
 ->select('*')
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__deals_deals'))
 ->order('category_id ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$products = $db->loadObjectList();
?>

<?php foreach ($products as $product) : ?>
    <?php echo $product->id; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But, I want foreach my products by category. eg:

first foreach

- Product category: 1
- product: name
- Product category: 1
- product: name

second foreach

- Product category: 2
- product: name
- Product category: 2
- product: name

etc..

if it possible to add many foreach loops it wil be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using the nested foreach loop.Keep your cat_id in outter one and your product name in inner one.
Thank you.